# Database credentials in PHP file

Tags: database, php-5.4

OK so I have a a PHP file that sends data to the Database and therefore has the username and password etc hard coded into the file.

I am not comfortable with this as I beleive there is a security risk.

Is there anyway I can pull these credentials from somewhere else? maybe using some sort of variable etc

here is how the details are stored:

```
$ct_host      = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'localhost') ? 'localhost' : 'localhost';
$ct_username  = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'localhost') ? 'root'      : 'username';
$ct_password  = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'localhost') ? 'pass'      : 'password';
$ct_database  = ($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] === 'localhost') ? 'phpdevel'  : 'databasename';
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about Magento

Comment: It sounds more like a random script. You would probably get a more useful response on either stackoverflow or http://security.stackexchange.com/. Specially the last one is founded for security questions

Comment: Just read the contents of the `local.xml` file? `$xml = simplexml_load_file('app/etc/local.xml');`

Comment: I understand where you're coming from but the script is in Magento head and wanted some help regarding pulling a variable like you would with price etc, if that is even possible

Comment: Ahh ok, in that case might I suggest posting the file path and part of the magento file code to your question to make it more clear what you want to do?

Comment: 1.) You are right. It's bad practise to put this in a php script file. And it would be even more worse to put and publish this in a version control.
2.) Do what B00MER said: Put it in your local.xml and read from the file
3.) Then just load it via Magento config $value = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('path/to/your/config');
Is that enough of a variable to work with?

Comment: And I wonder also: Why do you want to write directly to the DB and not use Magento functions for this?

Comment: This looks like what I need. I have added some more code. How would I implement what you have discussed in to it? thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want the standard Magento database credentials you can use the following

```
$config  = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig("default_setup");

$config->host,
$config->username,
$config->password,
$config->dbname
```

or

```
$host = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/default_setup/connection/host');
$username = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/default_setup/connection/username');
$password = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/default_setup/connection/password');
$dbname = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getNode('global/resources/default_setup/connection/dbname');
```

Or add a second connection just for your script in `app/etc/local.xml`

```
<config>
    <global>
        [...]
        <resources>
            [...]
            <default_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[magento_user]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[magento_password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[magento_db]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>1</active>
                </connection>
            </default_setup>
            <custom_setup>
                <connection>
                    <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
                    <username><![CDATA[custom_user]]></username>
                    <password><![CDATA[custom_password]]></password>
                    <dbname><![CDATA[custom_db]]></dbname>
                    <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
                    <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
                    <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
                    <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
                    <active>0</active> <!-- probably should be 0 or Magento will use it -->
                </connection>
            </custom_setup>
        </resources>
        [...]
    </global>
    [...]
</config>
```

And get it via

```
$config  = Mage::getConfig()->getResourceConnectionConfig("custom_setup");

$config->host,
$config->username,
$config->password,
$config->dbname
```

Comment: I just get a error 500 page but thanks anyway

Comment: @MikeTimTurner that means there is an error. can you turn on error display or check apache logs?